# Mapping through a hash of key/values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form being submitted that is saving multiple records, and the parameters look something like this:

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "_method"=>"put",
  "products"=> {
    "321" => {
        "sale_price"=>"10"
    },
    "104" => {
        "sale_price"=>"10"
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my controller, I have this:

```
@updated_products = Product.update(params[:products].keys, params[:products].values)
```

This expects the keys (321, 104) to be IDs.
However, I'm using the `to_param` in my model to change my urls from IDs to another column value.

Is there a way to take the `params[:products].keys` and swap them for the appropriate IDs so I can use IDs in the `.update()` statement.
I can use `Product.find_by_column_name(321).id` to get the id although I don't know how to do this. Still new to rails.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update) `#update` iterates through each key and runs `update_attributes` so it goes through all the validations.  You can change your method to

```
@updated_products = params[:products].inject([]) do |array, (column_id, attributes)|
  product = Product.find_by_column_id column_id
  if product.update_attributes(attributes)
    array << product
  else
    array
  end
end
```

This may seem a little complex but it is equal to this one below which is easier to understand and code read

```
@updated_products = []

params[:products].each do |column_id, attributes|
  product = Product.find_by_column_id column_id
  if product.update_attributes(attributes)
    @updated_products << product
  end
end
```

Comment: Your second block of code worked. The first one didn't, not sure why.